# There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, etl, data-warehouse

I'm trying to process dimension from Visual Studio Data Tools 2013. However, I get these errors:

1. Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
2. Server: The current operation was cancelled because another
   operation in the transaction failed.
3. The following system error occurred:  There are currently no logon
   servers available to service the logon request.
4. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not
   be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Asuntokunnat',
   Name of 'Asuntokunnat'.
5. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the
   dimension, with the ID of 'ALUE', Name of 'ALUE' was being
   processed.
6. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the
   'AlueTunnus' attribute of the 'ALUE' dimension from the
   'MultiDimension_Try_After_Changing_Instance' database was being
   processed.

I'm using MSSQL 2014 Enterprise Edition and my Instance is : Myname-PC

Datasource ConnectionString is:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=HARETH-PC;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Asuntokunnat
```

Although my Impersonation Information settings are Myname-PC\Myname for username and the password field is empty.

Comment: Ok guys, so the solution was that I had to use my windows authentication username and password. I went pass this sentence many times, but didn't know exactly what does it mean. So, for people who have same problem what is meant by windows authentication is the username and password that you use when you login to your windows machine, not the ones that you have used during SQL server installation (as I thought before). Cheers.

Comment: funny thing i don't have such password. Welcome to wasting time on resolving amazingly interesting issues with Microsoft tools. What do I love more is that I do it for my university project, well well well. <Depresed>